# How i open XIb file button to ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, xib

When i tap this `edit` button then i want to open WolverineVC

```
    class XibFileController: UIView {

           // This Is XIB controller File
           @IBAction func editButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
               // TODO: Click here to open wolverineVC
           }
    }
```

**here is the Xib File**[image]

**here is my Storyboard  file**

[image]

Comment: You want to open the Xib file that contains the edit button when you tap the edit button?  It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Get a reference to the storyboard, instantiate the controller and perform pushViewController if it is in the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  guard let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Wolverine", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WolverineVC") as? WolverineVC
        else {
            return
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

You need to add a storyboard ID to instantiate your storyboard.

[image]

edit: according to your updated question.

```
protocol XibDelegate: AnyObject {
 func openWolverineVC(value: Bool)
}

class XibFileController: UIView {

        weak var delegate: XibDelegate?

       // This Is XIB controller File
       @IBAction func editButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
           self.delegate?.openWolverineVC(value: true)
       }
}
```

Your main view controller should be like this:

```
    final class MainViewController: UIViewController, XibDelegate {
    

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad() 
     xibReference.delegate = self
  }

  func openWolverineVC(value: Bool) {
   guard let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Wolverine", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WolverineVC") as? WolverineVC
            else {
                return
            }
     viewController.boolValue = value
     self.present(viewController, animated: true)
  }

}
```

Comment: I updated my question for better understanding please have a look thank you.

Comment: And error came ~ Value of type 'XibFileController' has no member 'navigationController'

Comment: Because your xib is actually an UIView. You need to delegate it to parent class, which must be a viewcontroller. You can't present or push from an UIView.

Comment: And i want to pass `Bool` data to `WolverineVC.swift` file, you have any idea for this

Comment: `xibReference.delegate = self` i got error in this line

Answer (score 0):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "premiumPage")
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

- firstly, lets create a storyboard and then give a name (if your storyboard name is "Main.storyboard" the name is "Main" or Wolverine.storyboard -> name is: "Wolverine")
- go to your storyboard click on the page you want to open and give an identifier to it. (it name is Storyboard ID. seen in picture 2)
- now add above code to editButtonTapped function
- that's it

Comment: i try But a error came ~ Value of type 'XibFileController' has no member 'present'
I updated my question for better understanding please have a look thank you.

Comment: yep. Sorry The present method is not  a method of UIView

Comment: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
try change present method to this method

Comment: what error do you get. (write error message )

Answer (score 0):

I have a view that I created with xib. Clicking on the image in the view will direct it to the view controller I created in the storyboard. However, it doesn't happen anyway. Xib view code like this:

```
import UIKit
class BookDetailVideoViewController: UIViewController{

    var book : Book?
    var videoUrl = ""
    var url: URL?
    var index = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var bookImageView: UIImageView!
    //var book = self.book
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bookImageViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        } else {
            self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        }
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        //self.bookImageViewWidthConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.35
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        if let url = self.url {
            self.bookImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
        }
        
        self.bookImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        bookImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageClicked))
        bookImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
    
    deinit {
        self.url = nil
    }
    
    @objc func imageClicked(){
   
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = ""
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
        if let vc = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YoutubeVideoViewController", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? YoutubeVideoViewController {
            vc.book = book
            vc.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func initializeView(url: URL, index: Int , book: Book) {
        self.index = index
        self.url = url
        self.book = book
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    }
}
```

[image: BokkdeatilVideoViewController]

Answer (score 0):

YoutubeViewController is the viewController I created in the storyboard. I could not switch from xib to this view.

```
import UIKit
import YoutubePlayer_in_WKWebView

class YoutubeVideoViewController: UIViewController {
    var photoTapped: (() -> Void)?
    var book : Book?
    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: WKYTPlayerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mediakey = book!.mediaKey as String?
        playerView.load(withVideoId: mediakey!)
    }
}
```

Comment: delegate result nil. Maybe that's why it doesn't go to YoutubeVideoViewController